# AJAX post with model property

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to do Something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/AjaxTest', 
    data: {
        id: @Model.Prop
    },
    type: 'post',
    cache: false, 
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
    ...
```

However, It didn't work. I know that if I have a hidden field for it, like

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

then I can get the property value by

```
data: { id: $('input[name="Id"]').val() },
```

Still I wonder. Are there any way else to access the Model property more directly?

Comment: 'It didn't work' is not enough information to help you. Did you at least check the console for errors? Assuming that the value of `@Model.Prop` is a string, you need to wrap it in quotes: `data: { data: '@Model.Prop' },`

Comment: Are you calling your ajax call directly on your razor view?

Comment: What is your controller method signature?

Comment: You send the data with parameter name `data`, but in your second method you pass it as parameter `id`

Comment: I have updated my answer with what I expect you really wanted.

Comment: thx, Rory. That's what I look for.
devqon it should both be id, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data: { id: "@Model.Prop" } // may or may not need quotes depending on data type.
```

If you do this, it will be the value of the Model.Prop field at the time of rendering the page so any modifications to inputs using that property will not be reflected.

If you want the actual data from an input control that has been rendered using EditorFor, etc:

```
data: { @(Model.Prop.GetType().Name): $('input[name="@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "." + Model.Prop.GetType().Name)"]').val() }
```

This will render the javascript using the property name as the json index and the same name but including the model (and any containing models) prefix as the name of the element to find the value of.

Comment: The question shows 'data' but the field is called 'id'

Comment: The `model` object should not be in there

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do if you follow the Model pattern of java script. 
This is your java script file.

```
var JSModel = (function(){

       var model = {};


       var init = function(){
           //Perfome your operations
         };

       return {
        init:init,
        model :model  //return beacuse we want to acccess it in cshtml
      };

    })();


    $(document).ready(function() {
        JSModel .init();
    });
```

Now in cshtml, you will do this:
//Invlude your JS file here and then

```
<script>
JSModel.model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); // You will get the model in your js file. it will in JSON form

</script>
```